No sound in Debian 12 on laptop, pipewire problem?
It seems the default in Debian 12 is now pipewire. I have no sound on this new laptop. I am looking for the easiest solution (with pipewire or pulseaudio) to restore basic sound management. AlsaMixer tells me I have a Realtek AC245 chip.
aplay -L:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

aptitude search pipewire\|pulseaudio
i A gstreamer1.0-pipewire - GStreamer 1.0 plugin for the PipeWire multimedia server
p  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio - GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio (transitional package)
p  libkf5pulseaudioqt-dev - Pulseaudio bindings development files for Qt
p  libkf5pulseaudioqt-doc - Pulseaudio bindings library for Qt documentation
p  libkf5pulseaudioqt2-doc - transitional package for libkf5pulseaudioqt-doc
i A libkf5pulseaudioqt3 - Pulseaudio bindings library for Qt
p  libkpipewire-dev - KDE's Pipewire libraries - development files
p  libkpipewire5 - KDE's Pipewire libraries - libkpipewire5 library
p  libkpipewiredmabuf5 - KDE's Pipewire libraries - libkpipewiredmabuf5
p  libkpipewirerecord5 - KDE's Pipewire libraries - libkpipewirerecord5
i A libpipewire-0.3-0 - libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server
i A libpipewire-0.3-common - libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - common files
p  libpipewire-0.3-dev - libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - development
i A libpipewire-0.3-modules - libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - modules
p  libpipewire-0.3-modules-x11 - libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - X11 modules
p  mkchromecast-pulseaudio - Pulseaudio dependencies to cast with mkchromecast
p  osspd-pulseaudio - OSS Proxy Daemon: PulseAudio backend
i A pipewire - audio and video processing engine multimedia server
i A pipewire-alsa - PipeWire ALSA plugin
i A pipewire-audio - recommended set of PipeWire packages for a standard audio desktop use
p  pipewire-audio-client-libraries - transitional package for pipewire-alsa and pipewire-jack
i A pipewire-bin - PipeWire multimedia server - programs
p  pipewire-doc - libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - documentation
p  pipewire-jack - PipeWire JACK plugin
p  pipewire-libcamera - PipeWire libcamera plugin
p  pipewire-media-session - example session manager for PipeWire
p  pipewire-media-session-alsa - example session manager for PipeWire (alsa)
p  pipewire-media-session-jack - example session manager for PipeWire (jack)
p  pipewire-media-session-pulseaudio - example session manager for PipeWire (pulseaudio)
i A pipewire-pulse - PipeWire PulseAudio daemon
p  pipewire-tests - PipeWire multimedia server - tests and examples
p  pipewire-v4l2 - PipeWire V4L2 plugin
p  projectm-pulseaudio - projectM PulseAudio module
p  pulseaudio - PulseAudio sound server
p  pulseaudio-equalizer - Equalizer sink module for PulseAudio sound server
p  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth - Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
p  pulseaudio-module-gsettings - GSettings module for PulseAudio sound server
p  pulseaudio-module-jack - jackd modules for PulseAudio sound server
p  pulseaudio-module-lirc - lirc module for PulseAudio sound server
p  pulseaudio-module-raop - RAOP module for PulseAudio sound server
p  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf - Zeroconf module for PulseAudio sound server
i A pulseaudio-utils - Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
p  qml-module-org-kde-pipewire - KDE's Pipewire libraries - QML module
p  squeezelite-pulseaudio - lightweight headless Squeezebox emulator - PulseAudio version
p  vlc-plugin-pipewire - PipeWire audio plugins for VLC
i A xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin - Xfce4 panel plugin to control pulseaudio

EDIT
cat /proc/asound/devices
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 1- 6]: digital audio capture
  3: [ 1- 7]: digital audio capture
  4: [ 1- 0]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 1- 0]: digital audio capture
  6: [ 1-31]: digital audio playback
  7: [ 1- 3]: digital audio playback
  8: [ 1- 4]: digital audio playback
  9: [ 1- 5]: digital audio playback
 10: [ 1- 2]: hardware dependent
 11: [ 1- 0]: hardware dependent
 12: [ 1]   : control
 33:        : timer

I've tried speaker-test -Dhw:0,B -c2 -r48000 -f S16_LE with B in 0,3,4,5,31 as suggested from devices above, with and without headphones. Note that I can record sound, using sof-hda-dsp hw:1,6 using e.g. Audacity. But Audacity stalls if I select output with sof.
The part that seems to me relevant from usr/sbin/alsa-info:
!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp (card 1)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

No sound servers found.


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 1 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      HP-HPElitex360104014inchG102_in_1NotebookPC-SBKPF-8B41

"No sound server found"? Although:
me     1634  0.0  0.0  50316 17824 ?        Ssl  Jun25   1:02 /usr/bin/pipewire
me     1637  0.0  0.1  71676 48176 ?        Ssl  Jun25   1:08 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse


It looks like you are using Sound Open Firmware drivers, which seems to be more complicated than the common HD Audio driver. First, you should have the firmware appropriate to your system chipset installed in /lib/firmware/intel/sof/* - do you have it? See https://thesofproject.github.io/latest/getting_started/intel_debug/introduction.html for more context.

@telcoM: I do have a bunch of those, but I'm not sure how I can know whether I have the right ones?

@telcoM: is there a way to re-run the setup including nonfree drivers?

Hmm, the fact that the snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp module is loaded suggests your laptop might have the Skylake generation chipset, which seems to be a bit special regarding audio DSP firmware. If you run sudo dmesg | grep firmware, does it show any error messages regarding missing firmware? You might need the firmware-intel-sound package too.

Never mind: if the HP-HPElitex360104014inchG102_in_1Notebook means "HP Elite x360 1040 G10 2-in-1 Notebook", then you have the latest-generation chipset and not Skylake at all. It might be that the default kernel of Debian 12 is simply too old for it. Debian Backports seems to currently offer a 6.7.x series kernel for Debian 12; you might have better luck with that kernel version.

@telcoM: thx. Is there no way to check what the chipset actually is, and whether it is supported by current/6.7.x kernels?

Sure is. First run sudo update-pciids to ensure your PCI ID catalog is up to date, then run lspci -nn and add the output to your original post using code formatting. Even if nobody has yet added the appropriate text labels to the database, the vendor/product codes [XXXX:YYYY] should be recognizable by comparing to chipset datasheets if necessary.

Following suggestion by @TelcoM, there was the question whether chipset is supported rather than a sound server problem.
lspci -nnk -d 8086:51ca
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS [8086:51ca] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS [103c:8b41]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

And then I found solution on reddit :

PulseAudio [and pipewire I guess] does not interface with your card directly, it goes through ALSA, so I suggest you install the ALSA utilities and check there first.


install git version of alsa-ucm-conf. AUR has alsa-ucm-conf-git. If you don't want to do AUR, you can pull the ucm2 folder from the git repo and drop it in /usr/share/alsa.


Support was added in a series of commits March 11, 2024. Latest release is January 2024. https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/commits/master/

The 1.2.12 version did for me.
